# How to access a certain value in an array of nokogiri hashes from a scrape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

This is the specific bit of code I am using for the scrape:

```
require 'singleton'
require 'open-uri'

class ProgramHighlights < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.table_name = 'program_highlights'
  include ActiveRecord::Singleton

  def fetch
    url = "http://kboo.fm/"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    titles = []
    program_title = doc.css(".title a").each do |title|
      titles.push(title)
    end
  end
end
```

When accessing the titles array and eaching through it my output is:

```
(Element:0x5b40910 {
  name = "a",
  attributes = [
    #(Attr:0x5b8c310 {
      name = "href",
      value = "/content/thedeathsofothersthefateofciviliansinamericaswars"
      }),
    #(Attr:0x5b8c306 {
      name = "title",
      value = "The Deaths of Others: The Fate of Civilians in America's Wars"
    })],
   children = [
    #(Text "The Deaths of Others: The Fate of Civilians in America's Wars")]
  })
```

I specifically want to get "value"
However doing the following does not pull it:

```
titles[0].value
titles[0]["value"]
titles[0][value]
```

I've no idea why I cannot access it since it is seemingly a hash. Any pointers of a direction to go with this? I can't get the data in a simple JSON format, hence the need for the scrape.

Comment: What do you get if you take one `title` and call `title.element` or `title.elements` on it?

Comment: Undefined method element for element, while elements returns an empty array

Comment: What is `title.class`?

Comment: Nokogiri::XML::Element

Comment: Sorry - it's been a while for me, and I'm not near my computer which has a project that uses Nokogiri... Try `title.first`...

Comment: No, that's not right.  Ignore that.  `title.attributes.map {|attribute| attribute[:value] }` I think is what you're looking for.

Comment: Trying it now -- will edit with results. Its giving me "no implicit conversion of symbol to integer"

Answer (score 1):

To get the attribute value of a node, you can use [['attribute_name']](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D). For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'
html = %Q{
    <html>
        <a href="/content/thedeathsofothersthefateofciviliansinamericaswars" title="The Deaths of Others: The Fate of Civilians in America's Wars">
    </html>
}
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
node = doc.at_css('a')
puts node['href']
#=> /content/thedeathsofothersthefateofciviliansinamericaswars
puts node['title']
#=> The Deaths of Others: The Fate of Civilians in America's Wars
```

Assuming you want the title attribute value of each link, you can do:

```
program_title = doc.css(".title a").each do |link|
  titles.push(link['title'])
end
```